# Java ClassNotFoundException html error

Tags: java, html, applet, awt, runtime-error

I need your helps once again. I have started programming with Java quite recently and I'm trying to create my first applet. I am just using the most basic code:

```
package firstofthings;

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class FirstApplet extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("This is my first Java applet!", 20, 30);
    }
}
```

(The curly brackets are put in the right places, wont show up here in right place for some reason)

I am rather proficient in html, and I think it is the code in this container that is wrong, so if you could point me in the right direction that would be quite cool.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FirstApplet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet
          codebase="."
          code="FirstApplet.class"
          name="FirstApplet"
          width="640"
          height="480"
          hspace="0"
          vspace="0"
          align="middle"
        >
        </applet>
    <body>
<html>
```

I took away the tags or else it wouldnt show up, so here is the details of the error I got

```
ClassNotFoundExeption

Java Plug-in 10.5.1.255
Using JRE version 1.7.0_11-b21 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Owner
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Please edit your question to make it readable: remove all the code and pseudo-html, paste it back is as-is, no modification, the select each block and press the  `{}` button to mark it as code.

Comment: Formatted your question so it was a little more readable. Please use the code ("{}") button in future questions.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know so I will do that next time.

Comment: Did you put a file called 'FirstApplet.class' in the same location as the page your are browsing, the `codebase="."` means 'here'.

Comment: With the edit link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I dont know where I saved the Java code, you see I keep it all in the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: In that case have a poke around and see where the applet code lives in the compiled webapp... It may even be the case the the applet is a `jar` rather than a `class`, in which case you need to use the `archive=` property of the `applet` tag.

Comment: Ok its a jar file, whats the archive property? hahah

Comment: *"Ok its a jar file,"*  And where is the Jar file relative to the HTML?  What is it called? *"whats the archive property?"*  Is your Google broken?

Answer (score 1):

If `firstapplet.html` (the name of the HTML seen above) is actually at:

http://our.com/applet/firstapplet.html

Then the applet class (as loaded from a loose class file) must be located at:

http://our.com/applet/firstofthings/FirstApplet.class

If the class were in a Jar (highly recommended) or the codebase were set differently, it would change.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  I always guessed it was your code.